# When To Use 9-Patch

Tags: android, nine-patch

Is there any Android developer documentation that says when drawable resources can be 9-patch?  To put it another way, is there a document that says something along the lines of "the following items use 9-patch data, if available"?

From poking around and experience, I've learned that 9-patch graphics should be used for

- application launcher icons
- icons used in the "Add to Home screen" selection list for App Widgets, Wallpapers, and Folders
- desktop wallpapers and when otherwise using [BitMaps](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html), e.g. on canvases
- button graphics
- [view backgrounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3abackground)

I've been surprised to see that 9-patch data is ignored when drawables are used for menu icons and tab icons.

Comment: In general you'll want to use 9-patches any time your resource has a chance to be drawn at a different size than the original since they scale up much nicer. To my knowledge there is no hard and fast list of exactly which things they should be used for and not used for.

Comment: Using 9-patch for launcher icons is not recommended. Launcher icons are not stretchable and most, if not all, would also look very weird if stretched - they need to maintain aspect ratio - hence scaled instead of stretched. They should be provided in different fixed sizes and put placed in drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi etc.

Answer (score 3):

9-patches is best used when you have an image that needs a fluid width and/or height.

Example: In my app I had two custom buttons that stretched across the bottom of the view. Because screen sizes can differ, I used 9-patches to allow the buttons to stretch correctly.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not asking about when 9-patch "should" be used, I'm asking about when they "can" be used.

Comment: I believe they can be used as the background of any view (give or take a few).

Comment: You were reading my mind.  And the view documentation does say that 9-patch can be used for backgrounds.